How to stitch screenshots of maps together to make one big map
I want to have an interactive city map, where I can scroll around, can make notes on and can zoom in such that I can see individual houses (think of a Thomas Guide).
What I've tried

My idea was to try and stitch together 8 flat images into one larger picture I can scroll around on. I found Hugin. Which, as I know nothing about coding or at least Hugin (if its not coding), it is overly cryptic to me, but I'm willing to figure it out if anyone knows how it works or if it works for this.

I've found multiple guides for Hugin but none of them work as I believe they are all outdated. I just want to have a big picture of a flat 2D map.
This is as far as I got in Hugin:


interface- expert
upload images
make all the HFOV (whatever this is) 1.
make one of them that will be in the center the anchor
change lens type of all the other ones that aren't the anchor. (to what?) I couldnt figure out what they were supposed to be changed to so I made this question.


taking screenshots from a phone and computer, scrolling over, then taking another screenshot and placing the two images lined up side-by-side repeatedly.

Why this doesn't work: It is almost impossible to keep all the screenshots the same proportion as each other because one slight zoom-in or zoom-out changes the entire scale from lining up with those around it correctly, and if I use a PC so the zoom level doesn't change, it takes a VERY long time of trying to put together one screenshot after another precisely and I still don't know what program would allow me to do this.


I also looked into Google Map's API. But I don't want to pay for a program to do what should be trivial. Besides that and being cryptic, I was also unsure how to define the zoom levels and how big I'd like it to be, or where even to enter that information after I signed up for a google cloud account and tried the, "Choose a map view" option, since it described the function as, "Choose a basemap with controls that best fits your needs, using default, satellite, or terrain views and control settings like zoom" But it seems like I need proficient coding knowledge to go this route?



Taking screenshots is not the most practical way to download images from Google Maps. Since the map is served in tiles, you can download as many tiles as you want and it is much easier to merge. Anyway, that's not what you asked.Try a search starting with "download and merge web map tiles".

do you want something like https://www.philageohistory.org/tiles/viewer/ (switch off 'Modern Street Labels' to see the custom old map more clearly)

Thank you @xenoid for the recommendation that hugin pictures need to be at the same zoom level. Even if all the images are at the exact same zoom level, I still cannot see how to use the software to get it to stitch them together, nor can I find any up-to-date tutorials on how to use it for any 2D images whatsoever. As far as I can tell, this is a terrible application to attempt to stitch a panorama, (or side-by-side screenshots of a 2D map) together.

@Gabriel, I searched "download and merge web map tiles" and believe I found the most promising method yet. After finding https://github.com/AliFlux/MapTilesDownloader It seems like I have to download Python and try to copy/paste the code he wrote or something. I'm terrible at this and have no idea what I'm doing, but I'm downloading Python now to give it a try.

@Mapperz, thats essentially just the same thing as google maps. I'm sure I could use it just the same, but the problem is that I need to divide a SECTION of the map, so I can take notes or draw on that section, and keep those notes that are ontop of the map, saved. I could just take a bunch of zoomed-in screenshots of that map then edit the pictures, but then when going through them I would have a bunch of hodge-podge areas with entire gaps of area missing or overlapping, different zoom levels between the screenshots.

@Cguys I used that app and it works. There are others too, especially if you are not used to running code directly. For example, you can use QGIS, although you won't have to run code, you will have to learn how to use QGIS. You might find it easier with SAS.Planet.
